# Probability of Grouping boys and girls

Tags: probability

10 boys and 2 girls are divided into 3 groups of 4 each. The probability that the girls will be in different groups is?

Comment: ...low?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way is to suppose that person A has been assigned to Group 1. Note that $3$ of the remaining $11$ will be assigned to Group 1. The probability that person B is one of them is $\frac{3}{11}$. So the probability that A and B end up in different groups is $\frac{8}{11}$.

There are more elaborate combinatorial arguments.

**Remark:** At the request of OP, here is a more complicated argument. Without changing the probabilities, we may assume that the groups are **named** groups, say Groups 1, 2, and 3.

The number of (equally likely) ways to assign people to named groups is $\frac{12!}{4!4!4!}$. One way of seeing this is that there are $\binom{12}{4}$ ways to decide who goes into Group 1, and for each of these there are $\binom{8}{4}$ ways to decide who goes into Group 2.

Now we could directly count the number of ways to assign A and B to different groups, or do it indirectly by counting the number of ways to assign A and B to the same group. We do the second.

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to choose the common group. For each of these, there are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to choose the groupmates of A and B. And there are $\binom{8}{4}$ ways to decide on the members of the first unused group, for a total of $\binom{3}{1}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{4}$.

Divide by $\frac{12!}{(4!)^3}$ to find the probability A and B end up in the **same** group.   Fairly quickly, the expression simplifies to $\frac{3}{11}$.